# Django application not updating

Tags: django, wsgi, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get a django application configured on elastic beanstalk. The first push works fine, but after that I can't get the settings.py to update. I can change some other files, but settings.py is being cached somewhere. (Probably by wsgi, which is also being cached) Is there some way to wipe the running state and have it start with the fresh settings.py?

Comment: no idea how elastic beanstalk works, but generally you have to reload or restart the web server for the new settings to take effect. In apache, a config reload is good enough to restart the wsgi daemon; with gunicorn you have to restart the process to make it work.

Comment: For some background on how reloading in mod_wsgi works read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode